# Regex find and replace C# Encode a part of text in base 64

Tags: c#, text, replace, base64, richtextbox

I have a qwestion. How can i find and replace a part of text using regex. If someone help me, I will be very glad. Here is the code:

```
Regex yourRegex = new Regex("(?<=\\[base64])(.*?)(?=\\[\\/base64])");
string result = yourRegex.Replace(Uri.UnescapeDataString(Body)),Helpers.Base64Encode(Convert.ToString(yourRegex)));
letterData.body = result;
```

All what I need, is to find in body, text that will be between [base64] HERE [/base64]. And replace this text with base 64 encoded text without "[base64][/base64]"

Example:
[base64] Hi my name [/base64] is Andrew, how are you

Result: SGkgbXkgbmFtZQ== is Andrew, how are you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can turn the lookarounds into matches followed by optional whitspace chars as you don't want to keep the `[base64]` and `[/base64]` after the replacement.

Then making use of [Replace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace?view=net-7.0) with a callback function, you can take the capture group 1 value to be converted to base64.

```
var Body = @"[base64] Hi my name [/base64] is Andrew, how are you";
Regex yourRegex = new Regex(@"(?s)\[base64]\s*(.*?)\s*\[/base64]");
string result = yourRegex.Replace(Body, m => 
    System.Convert.ToBase64String(
        System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(m.Groups[1].Value)
    )
);
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Output

```
SGkgbXkgbmFtZQ== is Andrew, how are you
```

Comment: its work, thank you, but unfortunately not the way it should be. This solution doesn't take control on newlines in text.
For example:
[base64] Hi my
name [/base64]
is Andrew.
The resut will be wrong

Comment: @Oleg Then you can  use `@"(?s)\[base64]\s*(.*?)\s*\[/base64]"` to have to dot match a newline.